# Windows button on windows tablet in custom shell

Tags: windows, windows-8, tablet, autohotkey

I am developing a custom shell for a windows 8 tablet.  I would like to intercept the tablets windows button press event.  I am not sure how to do so.  I am currently working in c#, but would be willing to consider any possible solutions.  I have tried autohotkey, but the tablet button must not be the same as the keyboard windows key.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I vaguely remember reading that Windows 8 requires running with admin rights. Could you try that?

Comment: That was it. Thanks.  Now that I realize this is just a regular winkey, I should be able to handle it with AutoHotkey or windows keyhook functions.  I guess I was over complicating this.

Comment: My contribution wasn't great, but the answer worked. Could you mark the question as answered by clicking on the white check mark next to the answer. Thanks.